# Windows Registry changes will not work

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, themes, registrykey

I´m trying to make some changes(Wallpaper/Themes) on a windows7 enviroment, until now, I copied some files in to a directory with admin rights, so the "hard" part is over.

Trying to change the registryKey with a batch or with a Powershell file will work, as an Admin and as a normal-user.
The bad thing is, if I try to make the changes as an Admin, then the changes will be just for the adminSession. And I want to make the changes for the normalUser and every new user(with not admin rights).
I found that with a batch file, I can make some changes to my normalUser account:

HKCU:\Software\Micorsoft....\Themes\  and change the value CurrentTheme to my own Windows theme.

If I check my registry, I notice that the CurrentTheme value was accepted, and after a reboot stay so.

But Windows shows me the default theme... ¬¬

I tried to change "everything" to set my Theme as default, but nothing works..

Is there a way to make it works? Why windows is refusing to take the changes in the registry and always show me the default Theme?

Answer (score 0):

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
In the left pane, right click on Windows and click on New and Key. Type **Personalization** and press enter (if not already exists). 
Create a New and **String Value** called  **ThemeFile** and press Enter. Right click on ThemeFile and click on **Modify**. Type in the full path of the .theme file with file extension in "" (example: "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\NewCustomTheme.theme") ; it will be default for new users.

Comment: The problem is, if I run a batch datei for make a new key in the registry, I need Admin-rights. When I accepted ang give admin-rights to the batch file, then the current user will be the adminSession. "HKCU\Admin"

Is there´s a way to make something like, but direct in the all users tree [HKEY_USERS] , because if it so, I preatty sure it will be affect from the old users to the new ones...

Comment: The above should not affect old users because the theme profiles are already saved locally to their username profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Are the systems on a domain?

You should know that registry values stored within the Policies key and all the subkeys after that can be reset by domain group policy at any time.  That is to say that if you make a change here and reboot or run gpupdate, you can expect the values to be erased.

If you really want to change the theme for all users, you should use Group Policy to apply the theme, as seen in this link.  [Group Policy Settings for Windows Personalization.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617164(v=ws.10).aspx).  Look in the section under "Set a Specific Theme".

I've done this for clients a number of times.  You can also set a specific theme as the default by logging on as the Default Profile and making changes.  Keep in mind that this approach should be done when you build a system image to deploy to the environment.